# How to remove punctuation characters from a char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, visual-studio, char

My program prompts a user for a phrase to check if its a palindrome, then it's supposed to print out the phrase without capitalization or special characters like " ' , ? etc. My problem is erasing those characters. I've gotten my program to ignore them I'm asking how should I erase them? I made a comment where I think the statement should go. Example output should be: "Madam I'm Adam" to "madamimadam"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
    using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Variables and arrays
    int const index = 80;
    char Phrase[index];
    char NewPhrase[index];
    int i, j, k, l;
    bool test = true;

    //Prompt user for the phrase/word
    cout << "Please enter a sentence to be tested as a palindrome: ";
    cin.getline(Phrase, 80);

    //Make everything lowercase, delete spaces, and copy that to a new array 'NewPhrase'
    for(k = 0, l = 0; k <= strlen(Phrase); k++)
    {
        if(Phrase[k] != ' ')
        {
            NewPhrase[l] = tolower(Phrase[k]);
            l++;
        }
    }
    //cout << "The Phrase without punctuation/extra characters: " << newPhrase[l];

    int length = strlen(NewPhrase); //Get the length of the phrase

    for(i = 0, j = length-1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        if(test) //Test to see if the phrase is a palindrome
        {
            if(NewPhrase[i] == NewPhrase[j])
            {;}
            else
            {
                test = false;
            }
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    if(test)
    {
        cout << endl << "Phrase/Word is a Palindrome." << endl << endl;
        cout << "The Palindrome is: " << NewPhrase << endl << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << endl << "Phrase/Word is not a Palindrome." << endl << endl;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not delete this characters in the first loop just as spaces?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete element from C++ array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023011/delete-element-from-c-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify this line:

```
if(Phrase[k] != ' ')
```

To be:

```
if((phrase[k] != ' ') && (ispunct(phrase[k]) == false))
```

This means that we check for spaces and punctuation at the same time.

---

Also, consider rewriting this:

```
if(NewPhrase[i] == NewPhrase[j])
        {;}
        else
        {
            test = false;
        }
```

As this:

```
if(NewPhrase[i] != NewPhrase[j])
   test = false;
```

Comment: I tried this out and it worked, thank you so much :) I can erase the other statements for those while loops now

Comment: No problem!  Upvote/accept, if I answered your question.  Also, its possible to condense your code further.... you can check for a palindrome and ignore characters at the same time.  Removes the need for some loops, as well as the need for an extra array

Comment: @MikeChristiansen as in NewPharse i m getting garbage values after string tail

Answer (score 2):

Here's  suggestion:

1. Use an `std::string`
2. Use [`std::ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) to determine whether a character in the string is a punctuation mark
3. Use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to remove punctuation

That is one line of code (plus one extra line for a convenience lambda):

```
std::string phrase = .....;

auto isPunct = [](char c) { return std::ispunct(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); }

phrase.erase(std::remove_if(phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), isPunct), 
             phrase.end());
```

Next, for turning into lower case, from [my answer to this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190083/change-from-uppercase-to-lowercase-c/22190234#22190234), another one-liner:

```
std::transform(phrase.begin(), phrase.end(), phrase.begin(),
               [](char c)
               { return std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));});
```

Comment: Great!! btw, you solved my related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140385/stdremove-copy-if-valgrind-bytes-in-block-are-possibly-lost-in-loss-record)