# Change from uppercase to lowercase C++

Tags: c++

I want to change the input from uppercase to lowercase, eg. if the input is R - it changes to r. I want it with string not char. I have tried this

```
one=tolower(one);
two=tolower(two);
```

but it didn't work.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string one;
    string two;
    cout << "\nPlayer One, please enter your move: ('p'  for Paper, 'r' for Rock, '$
    cin >> one;

    cout <<"\nPlayer Two, please enter your move: ('P' for Paper, 'R' for Rock, 'S'$
    cin >> two;
```

Comment: yes i need to chnage the input to lowercase just in case if the user put uppercase

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::transform` and the right [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) overload:

```
#include <cctype>    // std::tolower
#include <algorithm> // std::transform

std::transform(one.begin(), one.end(), one.begin(),
               [](char c)
               { return std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
for(i = 0;i < one.size();i++)
{
    if(one[i]>='A' && one[i]<='Z')
    {
        one[i] = one[i]-'A'+'a';
    }
}
```

Comment: lab3.cpp: In function âint main()â:
lab3.cpp:15: error: âiâ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Your error is not clear.

Comment: he just copy pasted your code and didnt declare the variable i.

Comment: Oh it is 'i' between âiâ, I couldn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 
std::transform(one.begin(), one.end(), one.begin(), ::tolower);
```